# How to say more correct

Tags: meaning

I heard a saying which explains life's path of a person... It explains that if you chose your life's way (path), you should follow it until the end of your life...

> If you chose your way, go to the end...

The type of this sentence is more poetic, motivational or life's philosophy...
For example, if you chose the way to be a computer programmer, you have to improve your skills and growth even if you have got a problems with your education or something...
I mean that you do not have to give up ever never... So I am searching the most correct phrase to be like a credo type for me...

Comment: I prefer: "Wherever you go in life, there you are."

Comment: Can you [edit] to make your question very clear.  Make the title better. The title says "How to say more correct".  That doesn't tell me what your question is about.  What phrase do you want corrected? what is wrong with what you already have? Why do you think there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The metaphor of life as a *road* or *trip* is, I think, common across all languages.  It should not surprise you that sayings like this already exist in English:

> Life is a journey, not a destination

or this excerpt from Robert Frost's famous poem ["The Road Not Taken"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44272/the-road-not-taken)

> Two roads diverged in a wood, and I—
>   I took the one less traveled by,
>   And that has made all the difference.

In your case, you want to use this metaphor to extol the *virtue of persistence*.  Because you're asking for what amounts to *poetry*, there are, of course, many ways to express this.  There is no "most correct".

For example:

> Whatever path you choose to follow in life, follow it to the end.

Or

> Pick your way, and see where it goes.  Don't get distracted.

Or, more philosophically

> Life is a journey that must be traveled no matter how bad the roads and accommodations. Don't give up.
>
> All you need is the plan, the road map, and the courage to press on to your destination
>
> Never let a stumble in the road be the end of the journey.

All of which would make great [motivational posters](https://www.etsy.com/market/motivational_poster), by the way.

Still, there are many similar aphorisms that offer somewhat opposite advice:

> A person often meets his destiny on the road he took to avoid it.

Or, this from the great philosophers [Jimmy Page and Robert Plant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbhCPt6PZIU):

> Yes there are two paths you can go by
>   but in the long run
>   there's still time to change the road you're on.

Side note:  If you are interested in notable quotes on the virtue of persistence which don't use the "road" metaphor, you'll find many with an internet search.  One example:

> Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts.